# Simple push/pull between two "client" repositories to share changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I'm in the process of more correctly implementing Source Control via Mercurial at work and I've run into a situation.  My environment is two programmers with a Server and approx 4 dev computers. There are our 2 Office desktops where the majority of the code writting happens. And then there are 2 laptops used in the Labs for testing and debugging.
Previously, we had just been operating over the network; the code projects lived on the server and both my office and the lab laptop opened the files *over the network*. Yeah, I know it wasn't the best of ideas, but we made it work. Moving to a more correct model of DVCS with local repos presents with me with a problem: How do I get my code updates from my Office where I was typing to the Lab so I can program an actual chip? I feel like this level of changes (10, 20, 50, maybe even 100 little changes over the course of a day of development) doesn't need to go through the Server. Personal opinion is that commits to the Server should be reserved for when I'm actually ready to share what I have with others... not necessarily finshed with the project, just ready to share where I'm at.

Do I have to `push` to the Server and then `pull` to the Laptop everytime?
Can I just `push/pull` back and forth between my Office and the Lab laptop repos? How would I set that connection up?

Comment: What is "Server" in your case? Such term doesn't exist (or have *too broad meaning*) in DVCS-world?

Comment: @Lazy Badger -- It's just a file server, mapped to a drive letter on my computer

Answer (score 1):

**Under the assumption that the "Server" is CVCS-emulation in DVCS environment (i.e push target|pull source for all data exchanges exclusively) and "always working single branch" antipattern not used**:

Each Dev-host work with at least two named branches: personal (for WIP) and shared (merge-target) "default". WIP have to be pushed to Server, every other host Sync local repository with the whole Server's repository (but "authoritative source" is only default branch)

**Pure DVCS-model**

Except "Server" as default path, each Dev-host have 3 additional entries for other Dev's workplaces and pull-only model used for simplicity (no additional ACL and rules for pushes). I.e. (with human's communication) local http-server (`hg serve`) activated on source(s) on demand and on target developer `hg pull ANOTHERDEV`. Source server can' be stopped after it. Personal named branches isn't bad idea in this case also

Note: `hg serve can be always enabled on all 4 dev-hosts, combined pull command (pull 3 another repos) xan be defined as alias on every host and used when needed, without additional negotiation

Comment: `hg serve` is where things make less sense in my mind. Do I have to stop+restart the targets every time I want to pull from another dev machine? Or is it that once the http-server is running I can just keep pulling against it throughout the day to get more recent changes?

Comment: @Adam - you can start-stop "on demand" serving or have it always active (which doesn't require from you any additional operations - just pull when you want)